# LINQ: IF condition in WHERE clause not working

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq

I have the following LINQ query which is supposed to look into table Products and return me the records for the passed parameterr which are: a search term (string) and 3 boolean values for different "Type".

```
   var query = context.Products
                       .Where(a => request.SearchTerm == null || a.Name.Contains(request.SearchTerm))
    .Where(a => (request.isTypeA == false || (a.OrderType == "X" && request.isTypeA == true)) ||
    (request.typeB == false || (a.OrderType == "R" && request.typeB == true))
    || (request.typeC == false || (a.OrderType == "D" && request.typeC == true)))
    .Where (a=> a.OrderType != "U")
    .Where(a => a.IsInactiveFlag == false )
    .OrderBy(a => a.OrderType)
    .Select(c => new ProductType   
        {
            ProductTypeId = c.ProductTypeId,
            IsSelected = false,
            OrderType = c.OrderType,
            Name = c.Name,
            IsInactiveFlag = c.IsInactiveFlag
        });
```

**The issue**: The issue is that query always returns records by looking at searchTerm passed but it is not taking boolean parameters into account.So lets say for instance my search parameters are: searchTerm = "reference" , isTypeA = false, isTypeB = false and isTypeC = true. The above query will return all the records with searchTerm "reference" of all the different types and not just TypeC.

I googled a lot before posting this question but nothing was quite what I was running into. Please let me know what am I doing wrong. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
   var query = context.Products
                   .Where(a => request.SearchTerm == null || a.Name.Contains(request.SearchTerm))
.Where(a => (a.OrderType == "X" && request.isTypeA)
|| (a.OrderType == "R" && request.typeB)
|| (a.OrderType == "D" && request.typeC))
.Where (a=> a.OrderType != "U")
.Where(a => a.IsInactiveFlag == false )
.OrderBy(a => a.OrderType)
.Select(c => new ProductType   
    {
        ProductTypeId = c.ProductTypeId,
        IsSelected = false,
        OrderType = c.OrderType,
        Name = c.Name,
        IsInactiveFlag = c.IsInactiveFlag
    });
```

Comment: You are doing OR ( || ) on all your conditions, so your brackets are useless, if juste one condition is met ( request.isTypeX == false ), that will give a true and validate the condition.

Comment: Ok , I tried your suggestion and it is still returning all the records of different "Types"

Comment: So what are you suggesting, how should I rewrite this query so it doesn't return all the records ? @yeska

Comment: That works perfect! I am not really sure as to what was wrong with my original query.

Comment: You want to filter by IsTypeC = true. Imagine it's false, your condition Will return true because you are doing an or operator on IdTypeC=false and the brackets are useless when there are the same kind of operator inside and outside the bracket

Answer (score 0):

you should to explicit the bynary criterion of inclusion/exclusion about the OrderType next to each test of the filter value, that works as a switch....

```
  var query = context.Products
                       .Where(a => request.SearchTerm == null || a.Name.Contains(request.SearchTerm))
    .Where(a => (request.isTypeA == false && a.OrderType != "X" ) || (a.OrderType == "X" && request.isTypeA == true)) ||
    (request.typeB == false && a.OrderType != "R" )|| (a.OrderType == "R" && request.typeB == true))
    || (request.typeC == false && a.OrderType != "D" ) || (a.OrderType == "D" && request.typeC == true)))
    .Where (a=> a.OrderType != "U")
    .Where(a => a.IsInactiveFlag == false )
    .OrderBy(a => a.OrderType)
    .Select(c => new ProductType   
        {
            ProductTypeId = c.ProductTypeId,
            IsSelected = false,
            OrderType = c.OrderType,
            Name = c.Name,
            IsInactiveFlag = c.IsInactiveFlag
        });
```